# MAX Formula for Calculated Field or other way for sequential numbering

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, power-automate, calculated-column-formula

**The Question**:

How can I create a Calculated column with a formula that works the same way as an Excel MAX formula? Or other way to get automatically sequential numbering of items (00001,00002, 00003, etc.)?

**Why**:

I have a need to create unique ID's for process documents, but can't rely on the inbuilt ID field becuase if I delete a record SharePoint still reserves the ID for it. And the second reason - sometimes, there is a need to use the same 'ID' (e.q. to have second item for the same 'case'), so I can image that I will have numbering:
00001, 00002, **00003,00003,** 00004, 00005. So adding next item should input (or suggest) **00006**.

I tried to do it via Power Automate, but it do not fit my need because of long recurrence when another flow starts... I need to get that numbering immediately or within a seconds.

So ideally I was hoping to set the IdentificationDocumentNumber field default value as the result of `=MAX(IdentificationDocumentNumber)+1`, but I have no idea how to.

Comment: It is not possible using calculated column formula because formula cannot read ID (or any column values) from another rows. Formula can read column values from same row/list item only.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Ok thanks.... I just wanted to use Sharepoint to make some list, but for that I need to get sequential numbering immediately (not with 3 minutes delay due to Power Automate limitations...)... :/

Comment: Check if you can customize the list forms using Power Apps, generate sequential numbering using app formulas while creating/editing list item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to achieve your requirements using SharePoint calculated column formula because formula cannot read ID (or any other column values) from another rows/list items.

SharePoint calculated column formula can read column values from same row/list item only.

[image]

---

You can try customizing the SharePoint list forms using Power Apps, generate sequential numbering using power apps formulas while creating/editing list item.

**Documentation**: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)